# Unable to lock screen after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screen, lock

After upgrading to 12.04, I can't lock my screen anymore, has anyone encountered this and found a solution? Basically the keyboard shortcut does nothing and even if I select the lock option from the menu it still doesn't do anything at all. At the moment I have to keep logging out everytime I leave my workstation.

Thanks in advanced.

--Arvy

Comment: Apperently this is caused by gnome-screensavers not installed by default in my system during upgrade. After installing the package locking works just fine

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, the Lock Screen functionality stops working.
The likely problem is that gnome-screensaver has been uninstalled.
Just do on the terminal

> sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver

If you want to read more, can look on this [link](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-lock-screen-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

The above suggested solution did not work for me. I ended up solving my lock screen troubles using this article, may be you'll find this useful

http://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/