# Security bug when switching user account

Tags: 12.04, gnome, security

I face the following security issue on Ubuntu 12.04, Classic desktop.
There we have 6 user accounts on the machine.
One user logs on. Ok. Then a second user is using the User switcher logs in as well. That is also fine.
But the problem is, that if user2 tries to switch to user1 account, then no password is required. So all the logged in users just may switch to each others desktop.

May it be related with the above problem, that the screen locking is not working at all, even selected from the taskbar menu or clicking Alt-L.

Thank you!
Balazs

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another thread:
[Unable to lock screen after upgrading to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133479/unable-to-lock-screen-after-upgrading-to-12-04)

Sometimes, after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, the Lock Screen functionality stops working. The likely problem is that gnome-screensaver has been uninstalled. Just do on the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

If you want to read more, can look on this [link](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-lock-screen-does-not-work)